# Sass child effecting parents values

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make an input where I focus on the input field it removes the placeholder. My code looks as following...

HTML:

```html
<div className="container">
  <input id="input" placeholder="username" />
</div>
```

I have tried using the ~ operator as following in sass...

```scss
#input {
  height: 30px;
  &::placeholder {
     display: flex;
     padding-left: 6px;
   }
  &::focus {
    & ~ .input::placeholder {
      display: none
  }
}
```

and also the focus-within as following...

```scss
#input {
  height: 30px;
  &:focus-within {
     #input::placeholder{
        padding-left: 100px;
     }
   }
  &::placeholder {
     display: flex;
     padding-left: 6px;
   }
  &::focus {
    // set somehow #input::placeholder { display: none }
  }
}
```

But neither of these work so I would like to know how this is possible in SaSS. I know I could do this with js, but would want to do it in css.

fiddle with the idea..
https://jsfiddle.net/o0qftx3b/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `opacity` of the `::placeholder`, since it's not necessarily a `pseudo-element` like `::before` or `::after`. It represents attribute text, which doesn't necessarily adhere to the `display` property.

You can use this:

```css
#input {
  height: 30px;
  &::placeholder {
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
  &:focus,
  &:focus-within {
    &::placeholder {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
  <input id="input" placeholder="username" />
</div>
```

As a side note:

`& ~ .input::placeholder { display: none`
That would mean a sibling of the `#input` element on `focus`

Answer (score 2):

Use `&:focus::placeholder` where you set the `color` to `transparent`:

```
#input {
  height: 30px;
  
  &:focus::placeholder {

      color: transparent;

  }
}
```

---

```css
#input {
  height: 30px;
  
  &:focus::placeholder {

      color: transparent;

  }
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
  <input id="input" placeholder="username" />
</div>
```